# Data retrieval performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Using SSMS or Azure data Studio I can insert half a million rows into a temp table in 2 ms but retrieving the rows to screen from the table or the temp table take 13 to 15 seconds. I am unsure where to look next as to where the performance has been lost as this was not and issue a few months ago.

This is a production server that has been running for a few months now SQL 2017. This occurs whether I am on a client or directly on the server but on a basic PC with standard disks & Just 8 gig of RAM its up to three times quicker

```
SELECT SML.CONTACT_Id
INTO ##slr
FROM dbo.Stage_MailingLists AS SML;

SELECT *
FROM ##slr AS S;

DROP TABLE ##slr;

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 2 ms.
Table 'Stage_MailingLists'. Scan count 9, logical reads 13482, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(521001 rows affected)

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1187 ms,  elapsed time = 365 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(521001 rows affected)
Table '##slr'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1493, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 329 ms,  elapsed time = 8296 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Comment: "on a basic pc..." most likely means "on a pc that has no other activity". An apples to oranges comparison. And it also omits the time required to send the resultset over the network. No one outside of your organization can provide useful information. And waiting months to have this discussion only increases the difficulty in finding the cause (assuming it is not based purely on resource contention). Your starting point should be to ask your dba.

Comment: Moving data out of a database is a rather more expensive operation -- as is displaying it on some device.

Comment: Hi, I did ask the DBA he is as confused as me, I did the tests outside of working hours so load was near zero. I have worked with SQL for many years I understand the points you are making my issue is this performance is a huge drop off but there have been no upgrades / changes. This was just an example to see if people could give me any options to try, I have loads of queries running slowly on a server that idles at less than 10% CPU all day long which use to run quickly but suddenly have degraded considerably, 3 to 5 times slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Sophos antivirus had an update 'pending restart' that was causing a bottle neck restarted the server and all back to expected base line.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting data and displaying data is very different. When you perform an `INSERT` no data is returned to the client, everything is contained within the instance. The application doesn't need to interpret the returned dataset either and convert that into a display.

When you use a `SELECT`, to display the data, that data needs to be sent from the Instance, to the client; if that client is a remote host then things like network speed/traffic can be a significant factor for large data sets (you have half a million rows here, which is a decent amount to display). The application also need to interpret that data from the instance and convert it into a displayable format; in SSMS that might be converting it into the data grid. if you're throttling the client, then you may well also slow down the query as the data need to be loaded into the application's memory pool and processed to be displayed.

The speed of a `SELECT` and `INSERT`, especially for large datasets, may well not be comparable, as there are quite different operations.

Comment: Hi; Thanks for the reply I understand that, I was trying to show that server was functional etc, the issue is that there has been a massive drop off in retrieval that was not present before and I do not know what to test / bench mark i.e. could it be SAN related etc but if the data is RAM why would the SAN be an issue, so network but then why is it the same directly on the server as on a Client.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on SQL 2017, you can use session wait stats to measure the engine waits for the query.  EG install a procedure in Master like:

```
use master
go
create or alter procedure sp_exec_with_time_and_wait_stats @sql nvarchar(max)
as
begin

set nocount on;

with q as
(
    select *
    from sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats
    where session_id = @@spid
    union all
    select @@spid session_id, 'CPU_TIME', 0,cpu wait_time_ms,0,0
    from sysprocesses where spid = @@spid 
)
select *
into #waits
from q 

print ('-------begin batch--------')
print ( @sql )
print ('--------end batch---------')
set statistics io on;
set statistics time on;
exec ( @sql );
set statistics io off;
set statistics time off;

declare c cursor local for
with n as
(
    select *
    from sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats
    where session_id = @@spid
    union all
    select @@spid session_id, 'CPU_TIME', 0,cpu cpu_time,0,0
    from sysprocesses where spid = @@spid 
)
select n.wait_type, 
       n.waiting_tasks_count - coalesce(p.waiting_tasks_count,0) waiting_tasks_count,
       n.wait_time_ms - coalesce(p.wait_time_ms,0) wait_time_ms,
       case when n.max_wait_time_ms > coalesce(p.max_wait_time_ms,0) then n.max_wait_time_ms else null end max_wait_time,
       n.signal_wait_time_ms - coalesce(p.signal_wait_time_ms,0) signal_wait_time
from n
left join #waits p
  on p.wait_type = n.wait_type
where n.session_id = @@spid
and n.wait_time_ms > coalesce(p.wait_time_ms,0)
order by n.wait_time_ms - coalesce(p.wait_time_ms,0)  desc;

declare @wait_type nvarchar(60),
        @waiting_tasks_count bigint,
        @wait_time_ms bigint,
        @max_wait_time_ms bigint,
        @signal_wait_time_ms bigint
print (
'
SQL Server Wait Times (with CPU):

  wait_type                                                    waiting_tasks_count  wait_time_ms          max_wait_time      signal_wait_time')
print (
'  ------------------------------------------------------------ -------------------- --------------------- ------------------ --------------------')

open c
fetch next from c into @wait_type,  @waiting_tasks_count,  @wait_time_ms,  @max_wait_time_ms,  @signal_wait_time_ms
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

  declare @line nvarchar(2000) = N''
  declare @val nvarchar(60) = @wait_type
  declare @len int = 45

  set @line = concat(@line,left(concat(@val, space(@len)),@len))

  set @len = 20
  set @val = str(@waiting_tasks_count)
  set @line = concat(@line,right(concat(space(@len),@val),@len))

  set @val = str(@wait_time_ms)
  set @line = concat(@line,right(concat(space(@len),@val),@len))

  set @val = str(coalesce(@max_wait_time_ms,''))
  set @line = concat(@line,right(concat(space(@len),@val),@len))

  set @val = str(@signal_wait_time_ms)
  set @line = concat(@line,right(concat(space(@len),@val),@len))


  print ('  ' + @line)
  fetch next from c into @wait_type,  @waiting_tasks_count,  @wait_time_ms,  @max_wait_time_ms,  @signal_wait_time_ms
end
close c
deallocate c
print ('')

end
```

Then from your database

```
use AdventureWorksDW2017
go
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select top 1000000 *  into #x from factInternetSales order by 1,2,5;'
exec sp_exec_with_time_and_wait_stats @sql
```

Which will print your IO, CPU and Wait Stats like:

```
-------begin batch--------
select top 1000000 *  into #x from factInternetSales order by 1,2,5;
--------end batch---------
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 12 ms.
Table 'FactInternetSales'. Scan count 9, logical reads 1260, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 1260, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 1057, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 435 ms,  elapsed time = 335 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 435 ms,  elapsed time = 349 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Wait Times (with CPU):

  wait_type                                                    waiting_tasks_count  wait_time_ms          max_wait_time      signal_wait_time
  ------------------------------------------------------------ -------------------- --------------------- ------------------ --------------------
  LATCH_EX                                                     4879                 572                   0                  69
  CPU_TIME                                                        0                 435                   0                   0
  CXPACKET                                                       22                 331                   0                   0
  PAGEIOLATCH_SH                                                 26                  10                   0                   0
  PAGELATCH_SH                                                   17                   6                   0                   1
  PAGELATCH_UP                                                   74                   6                   0                   1
  LCK_M_S                                                         9                   3                   0                   0
  CXROWSET_SYNC                                                   8                   2                   0                   0
  MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT                                         601                   1                   0                   0
  SESSION_WAIT_STATS_CHILDREN                                    11                   1                   0                   1
  LATCH_SH                                                        3                   1                   0                   0
```